# show data from sqlite to listview using cursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

i am making a application where data is being saved in the database. but i am lacking in displaying the data in the list view using cursor adapter. don't know what code should be written. please check.

here is my code:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        private EditText nme = null;
        private EditText num = null;
        private EmployeeDatabase empObj;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            nme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageemp);
            Button btnShowData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

              btnShowData.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

              @Override 
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  onSaveClick();


              } });



        }

        public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                String varName = nme.getText().toString();
                String varAge = num.getText().toString();

                empObj = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                empObj.insert(varName,varAge,strDate);

                AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You have been Registered");
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.show();
                nme.setText("");
                num.setText("");



        }

        public void onSaveClick(){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowData.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

EmployeeDatabse.java

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class EmployeeDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    EmployeeDatabase (Context context) {
    super(context, "empdb.db", null,3);

    }



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
{

    // create your table here
    database.execSQL(
            "create table employeedetailnew" +
    "(name TEXT , age TEXT, time TEXT)"
                    );



}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEEDETAILNEW");
    onCreate(database);
// handle database schema upgrades in here  
}

public Cursor getDetails()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select name, age from employeedetailnew", null);
}
public void insert(String name, String age, String time)
{
    long rowId = 0;
    try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(); 
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("age", age);
    contentValues.put("time", time);
    rowId = db.insert("employeedetailnew", null, contentValues);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("The rowId is "+rowId);
        System.out.println("Name is "+name);
        System.out.println("Age is "+age);
        System.out.println("Time is "+time);
    }


    // insert into database here
}

public boolean deleteTitle(String name) 
{
    // incomplete delete code..:(
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("employeedetailnew", name + "=" + name, null) > 0;
}
}
```

EmployeeDetailAdapter.java

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EmployeeDetailAdapter extends CursorAdapter

{


    public EmployeeDetailAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shows_view, parent, false);
        }

        EmployeeOther empDtl = times.get(index);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        nameTextView.setText(empDtl.getName());


        TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age2);
        ageTextView.setText(empDtl.getAge());


        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time3);
        timeTextView.setText(empDtl.getTime());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        nameTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        ageTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("age")));

        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
        timeTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext());
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shows_list, parent, false);
         return view; 
    }

}
```

ShowData.java

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ShowData extends ListActivity


{
    private EmployeeDatabase databaseHelper;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        EmployeeDatabase empClick = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        { 
            do 
            { 
                String name = cursor.getString(1); 
                String notes = cursor.getString(2);
                String time = cursor.getString(3);
                // something must be written here
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        if (!cursor.isClosed()) 
        { 
            cursor.close();
        }

        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.employeedetailsnew.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/empname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/empname"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"

        android:text="@string/name_of_the_employee" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

        android:text="@string/age_of_the_employee" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ageemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/sub" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/show_data" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

shows_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

shows_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What you get? Any error? Post logcat information

Comment: i dont know how to user adapter to show data in the list.. other than this everything is fine.. please check ShowData.java code

Comment: Return `c.getCount()` instead of  `return 0;` in `getCount()` method.

Comment: please suggest me the code should i put in ShowData.java

Comment: First of all, you need to set an Adapter on your ListView.  Second, you should consider switching to RecyclerView in SDK 21.  It will supercede the ListView going forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `getDetails()` of  `EmployeeDatabase` with below code

```
public Cursor getDetails()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select rowid _id,name, age,time from employeedetailnew", null);
}
```

and change `ShowData.java's` `onCreate()` as below,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EmployeeDatabase empClick = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
    if(cursor !=null)
        getListView().setAdapter(
            new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(EmptyClass.this, R.layout.shows_view, cursor, new String[] {
                    "name", "age", "time"
            }, new int[] {R.id.name1,R.id.age2,R.id.time3}, 0));
}
```

and go through `SimpleCursorAdapter` and [this example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Answer (score 0):

***Change getDetails() of EmployeeDatabase with below code ***

```
public Cursor getDetails() {
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
return db.rawQuery("select rowid _id,name, age,time from employeedetailnew", null);}
```

**and change ShowData.java's onCreate() as below,**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EmployeeDatabase empClick = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
    if(cursor !=null)
        getListView().setAdapter(
            new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(EmptyClass.this, R.layout.shows_view, cursor, new String[] {
                    "name", "age", "time"
            }, new int[] {R.id.name1,R.id.age2,R.id.time3}, 0));
}
```