# Android Studio ListView from SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I'm working on Android Studio.I have a problem with displaying data from SQLite database on my ListView.
Here is a method to take data from SQLite(it works well,checked)

```
 public List<Terminy> getAllItems(){
    List<Terminy> itemList = new ArrayList<Terminy>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT id,data FROM Terminy WHERE Wolny = 1";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Terminy termin = new Terminy();
            termin.setId2(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            termin.setData(cursor.getString(1));
            itemList.add(termin);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return itemList;
}
```

And there is method to put data into ListView

```
public void ButtonLista(View v)
{
    ArrayAdapter<Terminy> adapter;
    ArrayList<Terminy> lista;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lista = new ArrayList<>(helper.getAllItems());
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Terminy>(this,R.layout.activity_panel_uzytkownik, lista);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**LogCat Error**

```
com.example.czou.proojekt E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView com.example.czou.proojekt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM com.example.czou.proojekt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 02-08 17:47:59.352 1779-1779/com.example.czou.proojekt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.czou.proojekt, PID: 1779 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Could some one help me ? I have read many tutorials so far and still don't know how to solve my problem :(

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: my method not working. When i click on button to show data on ListView my application stops and quit.

Comment: do you mind sharing the stacktrace of the exception/crash (aka *the logcat*)

Comment: yee exactly.Unfortunately,app has stopped error message

Comment: @Czunio post your logcat please

Comment: @John Joe com.example.czou.proojekt E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
com.example.czou.proojekt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
com.example.czou.proojekt W/art: Suspending all threads took:
02-08 17:47:59.352 1779-1779/com.example.czou.proojekt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.czou.proojekt, PID: 1779
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: It seems like there are something wrong with your xml layout.

Comment: @John Joe yee i know it,but i dont know how to solve my problem. It's my first app with Android Studio

Comment: Can you show `activity_panel_uzytkownik` layout ?

Comment: @John Joe u got it on Answer now

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296160/5806009)

Or try using a separate `Adapter` (`extends ArrayAdapter`) to have a full control over your layout and each piece of it.

Here is a tutorial about using ArrayAdapter [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter)

Another tutorial on how to use SQLIte with ListView [link](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.czou.proojekt.PanelUzytkownik">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="ButtonLista" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />
```

Comment: where are your `textView` ?

Comment: @John Joe i don't have it... thought that i need only ListView and nothing else

Comment: You need to have two layout in this case. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673829/arrayadapter-requires-id-to-be-a-textview-error) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916459/you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview-android-error)